# Getting Net:Readtimeout when launching chrome in docker from capybara

Tags: google-chrome, docker

I'm getting Net:Readtimeout error when I launch chrome in docker from capybara. I have tried to increase shm size (to 4GB) as well as suggested in many forums. But still i'm getting the error. Sometimes it works and sometimes it breaks. Can someone please help me as I'm stuck on this issue from many days.

Comment: Can someone please let me know how to handle it? I'm stuck on this issue and it's urgent for me to fix it.

Comment: What OS are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu docker

Comment: check docker logs for exited containers using `docker ps -a` and `docker logs <containerid>` and see if the chrome failed to launch

Comment: Yes, chrome launch is failing. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Any other information in logs which we can dig?

Comment: No didn't find any logs

Comment: Can someone please help? I'm stuck

Comment: can someone please help?